Device tree syntax
In Device tree, if I write:
 interrupts = <4 0>;

is it the same as:
interrupts = <4 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>;

?
Where can I found a complete Device Tree documentation that explains also this syntax (similar to macros") aspect?

Did you read the tag description of device? Replaced with device-tree.

Any equivalence will depend on the definition of IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW. Read your entire Device Tree source. Check what .h header files are included in both the .dts and .dtsi files. Use of the C preprocessor is AFAIK not documented in "Device Tree documentation".
